# A rumor is spread randomly among a group of 10 people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A rumor is spread randomly among a group of 10 people by successively have one specified person call someone, who calls someone etc. A person can pass a rumor to anyone except the person who just called and him/herself.

(a) How many different paths can a rumor travel through the group in three calls? n calls?

solution i saw:

In the n=three call case, you have 10 options for who
starts the rumor, 9 for who gets it next,
and 8 for who gets it third, and 8 for who gets it fourth. which is $(10)(9)(8)(8)$

i understand everything except the 2nd 8. where did that arise from? i thought it would just be $(10)(9)(8)$

Comment: It the first/zeroth person allowed to phone 5 people?! I don't get how that case is handled.

Comment: the zeroth person can phone any of the 9 remaining people,  but there are 10 ways that the rumour can be started

Comment: if someone passed the rumor to another one , then he received this rumor from someone else, can he pass the rumor again to that first person ? or the optioons are narrowed to 10-3 , 3 are (himself , first person whom he called, second person who called him)

Answer (score 3):

The factor of $10$ is for the choice of the source of the rumor. There are $9$ other people who can be the recipient of the first call, so there are $10\cdot9$ possible paths with one call. The recipient of each call has $8$ choices of whom to call, so there are $10\cdot9\cdot8$ possible paths with two calls: $10$ choices of source, $9$ choices of first recipient, $8$ choices of second recipient. Finally, the second recipient has $8$ choices for the third recipient, giving a total of $10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot8$ paths with three calls.

In general there will be $10\cdot9\cdot8^{k-1}$ paths with $k$ calls for $k\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

It specifies **in three calls**.  The rumor originates with a person, but nobody called the original person to tell him the rumor.  *The zeroth person starts the rumor himself*.

Pick who **started** the rumor.  $10$ choices.  (Note, I will *not* refer to the rumor starter as the "first person" but rather the "zeroth person")

Pick who the first person to be called is (by the rumor starter).  There are $9$ choices since the rumor starter will not call himself.

Pick who the second person to be called is (by the first person).  There are $8$ choices since the first person to be called will not call himself and will not call the rumor starter.

Finally, pick who the third person to be called is (by the second person).  There are $8$ choices since the second person to be called will not call himself and will not call the first person (but might call the rumor starter or anyone else).

Generalize this to larger numbers of people.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I think.  It came down to my interpretation of the paths.  At the third branching those people are allowed to contact the person that started the rumour so instead of there being 7 people to choose from there are actually 8